# Save objects in Realm only when Save button is pressed

Tags: swift, swiftui, realm

I'm trying to create a really simple app in SwifUI + Realm but I cannot understand how can I make it work. Basically I have a list of objects. When I click on a row it will open a sheet to edit the underlying object, if i press "+" it will open same sheet to create a new object.

In the sheet object will be save only if "Save" button is pressed.

Here is my model

```
class PayableEntityType: Object {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: ObjectId
    @Persisted var name: String
    @Persisted var iconName: String
    @Persisted var mainColor: String
    @Persisted var secondaryColor: String
    @Persisted var _partitionValue: String = AppInfo.partitionValue
    
    convenience init(name: String, mainColor: String, secondaryColor: String, iconName: String) {
        self.init()
        self.name = name
        self.mainColor = mainColor
        self.secondaryColor = secondaryColor
        self.iconName = iconName
    }
}
```

This is my list view

```
struct PayableEntityTypesListScreen: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode
    @ObservedResults(PayableEntityType.self) private var payableEntityTypes
    
    @State var selectedPayableEntityType: PayableEntityType
    @State var forEdit: PayableEntityType?
    
    @State var openForSelect: Bool = false
    
    @State private var showEdit: Bool = false
    @State private var isNew: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(self.payableEntityTypes.sorted(byKeyPath: "name")) { payableEntityType in
                    Text(payableEntityType.name).onTapGesture {
                        self.rowTap(payableEntityType)
                    }
                }
            }.padding(.top, 1)
        }.navigationTitle("Entity type")
            .toolbar {
                if !openForSelect {
                    self.newPayableEntityTypeButton()
                }
            }
    }
    
    private func rowTap(_ payableEntityType: PayableEntityType) {
        self.selectedPayableEntityType = payableEntityType
        if self.openForSelect {
            self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        } else {
            self.isNew = false
            self.showEdit = true
        }
    }
    
    @ToolbarContentBuilder
    private func newPayableEntityTypeButton() -> some ToolbarContent {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
            AddButton(action: {
                self.isNew = true
                self.showEdit = true
            }).sheet(isPresented: self.$showEdit) {
                EditPayableEntityTypeScreen(payableEntityType: self.isNew ? PayableEntityType() : self.selectedPayableEntityType)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the edit\create view

```
struct EditPayableEntityTypeScreen: View {
    @Environment(\.realm) var realm
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode
    
    @ObservedRealmObject var payableEntityType: PayableEntityType
    
    @State private var errorMessage: String = ""
    @State private var showingAlert: Bool = false
    
    @State private var name: String = ""
    @State private var iconName: String = ""
    @State private var selectedMainColor: Color = .green
    @State private var selectedSecondaryColor: Color = .black
    
    private var isUpdating: Bool {
        self.payableEntityType.realm != nil
    }
    
    init(payableEntityType: PayableEntityType) {
        self.payableEntityType = payableEntityType
        if self.isUpdating {
            self._name = .init(initialValue: self.payableEntityType.name)
            self._iconName = .init(initialValue: self.payableEntityType.iconName)
            self._selectedMainColor = State<Color>.init(initialValue: Color(hex: self.payableEntityType.mainColor))
            self._selectedSecondaryColor = State<Color>.init(initialValue: Color(hex: self.payableEntityType.secondaryColor))
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Info")) {
                    TextField("name", text: self.$name)
                        .disableAutocorrection(true)
                }
                
                
                Button(action: {
                    self.save()
                }, label: {
                    Text("SAVE")
                }).alert(isPresented: $showingAlert) {
                    Alert(title: Text("Warning"), message: Text(self.errorMessage), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func save() {
        if self.name.isEmpty {
            self.errorMessage = "Missing name "
            self.showingAlert = true
            return
        }
        
        
        self.errorMessage = ""
        
        do {
            if self.isUpdating {
                try realm.write {
                    self.$payableEntityType.name.wrappedValue = self.name
                    self.$payableEntityType.iconName.wrappedValue = self.iconName
                    self.$payableEntityType.mainColor.wrappedValue = self.selectedMainColor.toHex()
                    self.$payableEntityType.secondaryColor.wrappedValue = self.selectedSecondaryColor.toHex()
                }
            } else {
                self.payableEntityType.name = self.name
                self.payableEntityType.iconName = self.iconName
                self.payableEntityType.mainColor = self.selectedMainColor.toHex()
                self.payableEntityType.secondaryColor = self.selectedSecondaryColor.toHex()
                
                try realm.write {
                    realm.add(self.payableEntityType)
                }
            }
            self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        } catch {
            self.errorMessage = error.localizedDescription
            self.showingAlert = true
        }
        
    }
}
```

This code works, but I think is not the right way to use Realm property wrappers.

Note: the `PayableEntityTypesListScreen` has a `openForSelect` variable because I want to reuse that view to only select one of list elements and the close it.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Nothing is really jumping out at me as being problematic. Why do you feel it's not the 'right way'?

Comment: Thanks @Jay! Well, I just thought that the code, especially the save button, is quite messy

Comment: Nah - it looks fine. If it works, go with it. One thing to note, which may not be applicable, is that `.add` can have a `.modified` parameter where it will either modify an existing object, or if it doesn't exist, will add the object. Called an [Upsert](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/crud/update/#upsert-an-object)